# How to check the value is present in list or not using terraform 0.13.5?

Tags: terraform, contains, azure-resource-manager, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I need to check the value that exists in a variable or not and based on that I need to create resources.
If `value_list` doesn't have these `values('abc','def','ghi')` it should not create the resource.

What I'm trying here is:

1. Converting the string variable  to list
2. Check that list is having values 'abc' or 'def' or 'ghi'. If `value_list` contains any one of the values then proceed with the next steps to create resources.
3. If `value_list` doesn't have these `values('abc','def','ghi')` it should not create the resource.

**variables.tf**

```
variable "value_list" {
    default = "abc,def,ghi"
    type= string
}
```

**resource.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool" "user" {
  value_list = ${split(",", var.value_list)}
  count = "${contains(value_list,"abc") ? 1 : 0 || contains(value_list,"def") ? 1 : 0 || contains(value_list,"ghi") ? 1 : 0 
}
```

**Error:**

This character is not used within the language.
Expected the start of an expression, but found an invalid expression token.

How to check if the value_list is having the desired value or not?

Comment: Could you tweak the code that you have in your question to form a [mcve] please? Right now you have bits that make that unrunnable and it's hard to know if that's contributing to your error or where else the error lies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Terraform has functions that can help with that:

- https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/contains.html
- https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/setintersection.html
- https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/setsubtract.html
- https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/setunion.html

It looks like you are using `contains`, but in a strange way, if you need to split something you can do it in a local that way it is available to multiple resources, also the expression in your count does not look right you might want to look at the documentation for that:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/count.html#using-expressions-in-count

Here is a sample usage:

```
variable "value_list" {
  default = "abc,def,ghi"
  type    = string
}

locals {
  vlist = split(",", var.value_list)
}

resource "null_resource" "test_abc" {
  count = contains(local.vlist, "abc") ? 1 : 0

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo FOUND;"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "test_xyz" {
  count = contains(local.vlist, "xyz") ? 1 : 0

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo FOUND;"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "test_abc_or_def" {
  count = (contains(local.vlist, "abc") || contains(local.vlist, "def")) ? 1 : 0

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo FOUND;"
  }
}
```

See the count in that last resource:
`count = (contains(local.vlist, "abc") || contains(local.vlist, "def")) ? 1 : 0`

that is a conditional expression in the format:
`<CONDITION> ? <TRUE VAL> : <FALSE VAL>`

the condition is what looks strange in your sample code, you can have as many or in your condition as you want but don't mix the values there

**(**  `vlist contains "abc"` **OR** `vlist contains "def"` **)**

**(** `contains(local.vlist, "abc")` **||** `contains(local.vlist, "def")` **)**